# Jersey REST Service Output Format

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I need to format the output (xml) of a restful service using Jersey according to following scenario

I have a class with key value pair as follows.

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="columnValues")
public class KeyValueDTO {
    private String key;
    private String val;

    @XmlElement(name="column")
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="value")
    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

Suppose I have list like this which is returned by rest service:

```java
List<KeyValueDTO> mylist = new ArrayList<KeyValueDTO>();
KeyValueDTO dto1 = new KeyValueDTO();
dto1.key = "Name";
dto1.val = "alex";

KeyValueDTO dto2 = new KeyValueDTO();
dto2.key = "Age";
dto2.val = 23

mylist.add(dto1);
mylist.add(dt02);
```

And I want to generate the output as follow

```xml
<Name>alex</Name>
<Age>20</Age>
```

But currently it is giving following output

```xml
<column>Name</column>
<value>alex</column>
<column>Age</column>
<value>20</column>
```

Can anyone let me know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an XmlAdapter:

```java
public class KeyValueAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, List<KeyValueDTO>> {

  @Override
  public List<KeyValueDTO> unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
    // Needs implementation
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public String marshal(List<KeyValueDTO> vs) throws Exception {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (KeyValueDTO v: vs) {
      buffer.append(String.format("<%s>%s</%1$s>", v.key, v.val));
    }
    return buffer.toString();
  }

}
```

And then add that adapter to your bean:

```java
@XmlRootElement
public static class Wrapper {
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(KeyValueAdapter.class)
  List<KeyValueDTO> dtos;
}
```